# hbsfy outputs hbsfy code on compile - using Gulp + Browserify

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, gulp, browserify

I am trying to get any variation of hbsfy or browserify-handlebars to compile correctly using browserify. Compiling results in the handlebars.js(hbsfy) code outputting to my browser. I've tried just using the browserify command `browserify -t hbsfy app.js > bundle.js` but it doesn't change anything

I haven't the reputation to post images but basically this is the output:

> var templater = require("handlebars/runtime").default.template;module.exports = templater(function (Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) { this.compilerInfo = [4,'>= 1.0.0']; helpers = this.merge(helpers, Handlebars.helpers); data = data || {}; var buffer = "", stack1, helper, functionType="function", escapeExpression=this.escapeExpression; buffer += "
>   Hello "; if (helper = helpers.name) { stack1 = helper.call(depth0, {hash:{},data:data}); } else { helper = (depth0 && depth0.name); stack1 = typeof helper === functionType ? helper.call(depth0, {hash:{},data:data}) : helper; } buffer += escapeExpression(stack1) + "
>   "; return buffer; });

My template (template.hbs) is simply `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`

My gulpfile setup:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var hbsfy = require('browserify-handlebars');
//var hbsfy = require('hbsfy'); //this one shows up the same way

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
        return gulp.src('./app/app.js')
        .pipe(browserify({
            transform: [hbsfy]
        }))
        .pipe(rename('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

and my js file:

```
var Handlebars  = require('hbsfy/runtime');
var $           = require('jquery'),
 router         = require('./router/routerDefault'),
 template       = require('./template.hbs');

$(document).ready(function(){
    document.body.innerHTML = template({name: 'browserify'});
})
```

Does anyone have any experience on how to handle this? Any suggestions would be heplful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of this issue is redundant compiling. Listing a transform in both the packages.json and the gulpfile.js will perform it twice, I believe. In my packages.json, I now just use this 'node':

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "hbsfy"
    ]
  },
```

This will compile your templates for you. Your gulpfile.js DOES NOT require this section:

```
.pipe(browserify({
            transform: [hbsfy]
        }))
```

You can use either one. My scripts gulp task now looks like this:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
        return browserify('./app/app.js')
                .bundle()
                .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'))
                .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

Comment: Thanks this saved me. I was doing the transform on watchify 'update' each time instead of just once and it was mangling things up

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing something similar.

Just curious, what OS are you using? Seems to affect Mac but Windows seems OK.

I'm not entirely sure what's causing this but I stopped using gulp-browserify as it is now blacklisted.

I followed the suggestions from this blog post and it seems to solve the issue: http://viget.com/extend/gulp-browserify-starter-faq

The last bit is most relevant.

---

EDIT:

While using gulp-browserify, I would also check if you've listed your transforms in package.json. I think you may only need to specify transforms in one place (either in gulpfile as you have now or in package.json).

Comment: consider improving your answer by adding the excerpts from that last most relevant bit

Comment: I was able to get a successful compile but only on a barebones app.

I am trying to figure out how he actually did his template compiling. Does the `"browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim",
      "coffeeify",
      "hbsfy"
    ]
  },` actually do the compiling?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that link. I had been to his page several times before but his presentation hadn't really made clear how to specifically hbsfy. However, I gathered that I needed only 1 transform in the files.

Comment: Interesting. I was only running into this issue on Mac. Listing the transform twice in Windows didn't seem to produce the error, although it still works when removing from package.json. Well, glad you got it working.